# $http get catch ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, promise, angular-promise

Any way to catch these in an Ionic app?

> ionic.bundle.js:25000 GET http://192.168.43.40/?custom=1&cmd=2009 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

From a

```
$http.get('http://' + ip + '/?custom=1&cmd=' + cmd);
```

I've tried various combinations of .then, .catch, .finally,  etc i.e.

$http.get().then(..).catch()

I still get the above error in console.

> ionic.bundle.js:25000 GET http://192.168.43.40/?custom=1&cmd=3017
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED(anonymous function) @
>   ionic.bundle.js:25000sendReq @ ionic.bundle.js:24793serverRequest @
>   ionic.bundle.js:24503processQueue @ ionic.bundle.js:29127(anonymous
>   function) @ ionic.bundle.js:29143Scope.$eval @
>   ionic.bundle.js:30395Scope.$digest @ ionic.bundle.js:30211(anonymous
>   function) @ ionic.bundle.js:30434completeOutstandingRequest @
>   ionic.bundle.js:19194(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:19470

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing in local, I suggest to check if your ionic server is running on some port, because in the log you wrote it was not present. The connection refused statement suggests that you are not reaching the right address in ionic test server.

Comment: Thanks no I know the address isn't valid, I'm looking for addresses that are. I want a way of catching these errors.